# Htaccess - Silently converting pretty url to a php script with get var

Tags: .htaccess

I am using PHP and I want to use URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/username,
```

Instead of using a query string like this:

```
profile.php?u=username
```

How can I set up my `.htaccess` file to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !profile.php
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

This will pass anything after the domain name as a GET variable named `user` to `http://www.example.com/profile.php`

So this:

```
 http://www.example.com/User123
```

Will become:

```
 http://www.example.com/profile.php?user=User123
```

This will happen silently, so while your server will see the ugly `profile.php` URL, the browser will still show the "pretty" `example.com/User123` version to the user.

---

Since you asked for a more thorough explanation on what's going on, here it is:

`RewriteRule` is a bit like an if statement. Basically you're saying "if the request matches this pattern, redirect the request to this other file."

The pattern we're matching against is `^(.*)$` which breaks down as follows:

- `^` means "begin looking for a match at the very beginning of the string
- `.*` means "match on any number (`*`) of any character (`.`)
- `$` means "stop matching at the end of the string.

When you combine these together, it basically amounts to "match any request."

The parentheses around `.*` tells mod_rewrite to store anything that matches the part of the rule they surround in a variable. The variable they get stored in is called `$1` (if we had multiple sets of parentheses, they would be stored in `$2`, `$3`, and so on).

This `$1` variable is used to define the new path specified in the last part of the RewriteRule.

`RewriteCond` is like throwing another if statement around the `RewriteRule`. It says "only execute the RewriteRule below if this condition is true."

In your case the RewriteCond says to only execute the rule if the file being requested in the URL (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`) *isn't* "profile.php"

The implication of this is that requests for "profile.php" are processed as normal, but requests for anything else are redirected to point to profile.php.

The `[L]` at the end just means "don't execute any RewriteRules after this one". The L stands for "Last".

Clear as mud?

Comment: Thanks for Help,But still this not working it giving me script name only, Ex for same code it giving me :Array ( [user] => profile.php ) 
But sure I wants to same url as you mention above  http://www.example.com/User123

Comment: @Neelesh: It should only give you `[user] => profile.php` if you navigated to `example.com/profile.php`. If you go to `example.com/User123` it should give you `[user] => User123`.

Comment: I was using same Like http://localhost:81/test/neelesh ,

This code giving me profile.php Array ( [user] => profile.php ) 

In profile.php <? print_r($_GET); ?>

Comment: @Neelish: I updated the code so that the RewriteRule won't affect requests already routed to the file. You should be good to go now.

Comment: Ohh great, Its working now,

Thanks so much, I'm very thankful to you If you could little bit explain me how its worked.

BY the way thanks so much.

Comment: @Neelesh: Great! Since my answer worked for you, could you please mark it as "Accepted" by clicking on the checkmark next to this answer?

Comment: @Neelesh: I added the explanation you wanted. Let me know if that explains things for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://www.example.com/(.*) profile.php?u=$1
```